# How can I make my code more optimised with functions?

Tags: python, optimization

I have a code:

```
R1 = sheet_val['A3'].value

R2 = sheet_val['A4'].value

R3 = sheet_val['A5'].value

R4 = sheet_val['A6'].value

R5 = sheet_val['A7'].value

R6 = sheet_val['A8'].value

R7 = sheet_val['A9'].value


al = (R, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7)

my = iter(al)
```

**p.s: Here I extract data from excel and place it into array**

So the question how can I optimize my code?
I tried with making a function, but it didn't get on.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Comment: @jonathan already helped

Comment: al = tuple([sheet_val[f'A{i}'].value for i in range(3,10)])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this code to make your code more elegant:

```
al = tuple([sheet_val[f'A{i}'].value for i in range(3,10)])
```